# How to deal with changing xpath, Selenium Webdriver, Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I tried to understand it on the basis of other topics but need support using my example.

The page generates two xpaths for 1 element that i want to click on, which differ slightly, so:

```
"//*[@id='react-root']/section/main/article/header/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a/span"
"//*[@id='react-root']/section/main/article/header/div[2]/ul/li[2]/span/span"
```

```html
<a class="_s53mj" href="/these.charming.dogs/followers/"><!-- react-text: 24 --><!-- /react-text --><span class="_bkw5z" title="3,071">3,071</span><!-- react-text: 26 --> followers<!-- /react-text --></a>
```

I want to get the number of followers of Instagram profile, for example: https://www.instagram.com/these.charming.dogs/

Later I use the number of observers changing, to see if it is greater than 1000

What should I do to make the script able to click on this item? I notice that xpath is different only in the penultimate field

Comment: Share `HTML` for the same

Comment: Sorry, i forgot about it, i added more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some alternatives:

css:  `header ul>li span[title]`

css: `header span[title]`

css: `header li+li span[title]`

css: `header span span[title], header a span[title]`

xpath: `//header//ul/li//span[@title]`

xpath: `//header//ul/li[2]//span[@title]`

xpath: `//header//span[@title]`